# Order by epoch isnt giving correct output in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, epoch

[image]

Have tried ordering by epoch as well as hhmmss - none of it is giving correct  output

Expected the output to be in a chronological order

Comment: Its strange that your query is in parenthesis. Usually that makes it into a type of result set (which in and of itself does not promise any particular ordering). Why are you doing that? What type of Database/Query Language is this?

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text. Provide query and data as properly formatted text instead.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. You're ordering by updated_epoch (_col5) and it is ordered. If you want to order by epoch column, just tell it so: ORDER BY epoch desc;